# Having difficulty with sql WHERE > 'value' statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a MYSQL query that will return all services with an id above a particular value. The query works fine when I use a static value as the comparative to 'id' such as:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM services WHERE id > '14'";
    if ($query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
            echo $service_id = $results['id'].'<br>';
            echo $service_name = $results['name'].'<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }
```

However if i use a variable like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM services WHERE id > $service_id";
    if ($query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
            echo $service_id = $results['id'].'<br>';
            echo $service_name = $results['name'].'<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }
```

the query does not return any values

Comment: **warning** your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: obviously service_id is not numeric. do `var_dump($service_id)` before `$query = ...` to see whats in there

Comment: Thanks for your concern about this but this code is taken greatly out of context here, there is no text user input where sql injection can be used and i have not implemented any other security measure yet since I haven't got the code working in the first place

Comment: x4rf41 you're right, my variable was not numeric but even after changing it to an integer, the query still doesn't return any results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hard coded the value you put quotes around it. 
Make sure that $service_id is represented as a string.

Try

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM services WHERE id > '$service_id'";
    if ($query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($results = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)) {
            echo $service_id = $results['id'].'<br>';
            echo $service_name = $results['name'].'<br>';
        }
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this and that made no difference. I think x4rf41 may have a point about my variable not being numeric

Comment: @metrosmurph Echo the Query so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I just worked out the problem myself, it was something else in the php file that I hadn't included in the code at the top. Sorry! Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM services WHERE id > '".$service_id."'";
```